# iOS app talking to a Mac

Tags: ios, macos, networking

I need to build a networking application for talking to a Mac from an iOS device.

Basically I'm trying to write a remote-control type of application for my Mac, and will need to send things like mouse-movement and keyboard-events.

But to start with, how do I talk to the Mac over the network, what API's or technologies should I use from the iOS device to do this with?

Answer (score 3):

[This tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) on networking with Bonjour is gonna help you get started.

Comment: where is the tutorial? it opens the Mobileorchard.com webpage.  Please guide me to get the tutorial.